# Connect Google Analytics properly for a website that is accessible from 2 subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, multi-subdomains

I have a website that is accessible from 2 subdomains. For example `one.example.net` and `two.example.net`.

These 2 subdomains send the user to the same website and they do not have any different functionality.

I have one GA property that is already configured with the `one.example.net`. How can I include `two.example.net` to also send data to my GA property? Does Google Analytics do this automatically? Do I have to create another Data Stream or another property? I would like to see the 2 alternatives:

1. Aggregate metrics without being able to distinguish which subdomain are
   coming from. (Different data stream?)
2. Separate metrics per subdomain. (Different property?)

Answer (score 2):

i would place GTM on both subdomains, and use the same UA code if you want the data all in one place.

For everything i've ever needed it to do, GA subdomain tracking works fine / natively / automateically now (unlike in the past when you used to have to set it up like cross domain tracking).

try it out. if im wrong, let me know and ill look into it for you.

i havent tried with G4 yet but i assume its the same or better